# How to return a function with boolean value if a value is false in array of object?

Tags: javascript

I know there are plenty of methods to check if a value exists in an array but I want to try it out with a simple for loop,
Here is what I have tried in a simple for loop

```
const data = [
  {checked: true},
  {checked: true},
  {checked: true},
  {checked: true}
]
check1();
function check1() {
  console.log(check2()); // It doesnt print true
}
function check2() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    if (data[i].checked == false) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

The above function check2 should print console but it doesn't.

Comment: ?? None of the entries in the array are `false`

Comment: `JS Error: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined` - That's since your array has a length of 4 and you loop has 10 iterations.. data[4-9] is undefined.

Comment: yes so i want the function to return true

Comment: use `data.length` instead of 10 in the condition clause of your for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are out of length of array object so you need to put control if `undefined`
or in for loop you will limit with `data.length` rather than writing `10`

```js
const data = [
  {checked: true},
  {checked: true},
  {checked: true},
  {checked: true}
]
check1();
function check1() {
  console.log(check2()); // It doesnt print true
}
function check2() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    
    if (data[i] && data[i].checked == false ) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: @ pc_coder can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61563473/return-true-if-at-least-one-of-the-checkbox-is-checked-otherwise-return-false

Answer (score 3):

You are getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'checked' of undefined` because you are looping 10 times but your data doesn't have that many elements that's why it is not logging `true` value. So now you can use `data.length` or limit it up to length **4** or add a check of **undefined** condition

```js
const data = [
  {checked: true},
  {checked: true},
  {checked: true},
  {checked: true}
]
check1();
function check1() {
  console.log(check2()); // It doesnt print true
}
function check2() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (data[i].checked === false) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: @ Always sunny can you answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61563473/return-true-if-at-least-one-of-the-checkbox-is-checked-otherwise-return-false